# How to remove space (margin/padding) of ion-row and ion-col in ionicreact5?

Tags: ionic5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLygS.png)
how can i remove the default padding in a grid in ionic5..I used the given code.but it doesn't work

```
<IonRow>
     <IonCol col-6 no-padding>
         <IonButton  expand="full" no-margin>NEWER</IonButton>
     </IonCol>
     <IonCol col-6 no-padding>
         <IonButton  expand="full" no-margin>OLDER</IonButton>
     </IonCol>
   </IonRow>
```

Comment: Did you mean to post an image? If so, your post does not have one

Comment: plz refer the link..i need to remove the spacing between the newer button and older button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this
class="ion-no-padding"